# overridePendingTransition doesn't work if android:windowIsTranslucent is set to true on Android 11

Tags: android

I have an Activity which has a translucent background, in the theme I have:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
```

When the Activity is closed I use:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.scale_fade_in, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

This works fine on any Android version up to Android 10. However, on a device running Android 11 the Activity simply closes and no animation is run.

If I set `android:windowIsTranslucent` to `false` in the theme the transition works correctly but I obviously lose the translucent background I need.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Still the case in Android 12. — What I needed was the exact opposite of you: no animation when leaving the activity, so my workaround was to set the visibility of the entire activity to gone and the status bar color to transparent before calling finish(). Not great, but does the job.